# How to do nested routing using one template & controller in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have a main template main.html, now I have say few links in this page.

```
  `<a href="albums/bollywood">bollywood </a>`
  <a href="albums/tollywood">tollywood </a>
```

- Now in turn bollywood page, has again links

  `<a href="album/bollywood/hindi/"> Hindi </a>`

Now in turn this page again have links as
    `<a href="album/bollywood/hindi/old"> Old </a>`

And chains goes on.

Now what I want is every url has one template to render.
I want to have one configration as:-

```
`$routeProvider(when('/albums/:albumName),
 {
     templateUrl : 'albumsList.html',
     controller : 'albumsCtrl'
 })`
```

I want to specify that whateveer follows /albums/* , using $routeParams collect that value in albumName.

In my scenario,I don't see any need to need to use ui-routes.

Comment: Solution to your problem - https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Comment: ui-router is de the facto solution while we wait for the new AngularJS 2.0 routing system, which ui-router has influenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use * in $routeProvider that will match all the characters in the url, when **:** is used it will match all characters till **/**.

Change your code

```
$routeProvider(
when('/albums/:albumName),
 {
     templateUrl : 'albumsList.html',
     controller : 'albumsCtrl'
 })
```

To

```
$routeProvider(
when('/albums/:albumName*),
 {
     templateUrl : 'albumsList.html',
     controller : 'albumsCtrl'
 })
```

Reference: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider

Comment: Barely 8 seconds when the answer was submitted and you already accepted it? Wow!

Comment: @callmekatootie... yeah buddy I almost reached the same trick and very next second I saw the answer posted by Vishal...

Vishal Thank you :)